# Specifying Rate of Change in the Objective Function

Tags: gekko

I would like to solve some optimization problems with the following objective function
[image]

Basically, I want to control the rate of change of x. I am not quite sure what is the most decent way to set up the objective function like this in GEKKO using m.Minimize().

The idea is to approximate the derivative dx/dt using finite difference, let say the most intuitive one: forward difference.

I have tried many different ways, but all of them failed.
Below I show all approaches I have done. Note that all the ODEs for x(t) and parameters are specified correctly, and so I do not show all of them here.

(1) The naivest one is something like

```
obj = 0
for i in range(nt-1):
    obj = obj + ((1/dt)*(x[i+1]-x[i])-0.5)**2

m.Minimize(obj)
```

The error is: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

(2) Then I tried to create a finite difference matrix like (*`nt` is the number of time points)

```
q = np.diag(-1*np.ones(nt)) + np.diag(1*np.ones(nt-1),1)
q[-1,-1] = 0
diff = m.Param(value = q)
```

And then, set the objective to be

```
obj = ((1/dt)*(diff@x)- 0.5)**2
```

Basically, I tried to use a similar approach when we optimize the final value, where we define a vector where all entries are zero except the final one. However, I got an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'GKParameter' and 'GKVariable'

(3) I read some other previous posts on optimization and so tried something like

```
q = np.diag(-1*np.ones(nt)) + np.diag(1*np.ones(nt-1),1)
q[-1,-1] = 0

for i in range(nt):
    diff = m.Param(value=q[i])
    m.Minimize(m.abs3((1/dt)*(diff*x)-0.5)**2)
```

There is no error, but the solver did not even run.

To be honest, I feel like I do not clearly understand how things work inside m.Minimize, even after going through some documentation and previous posts, and so I cannot set the objective function properly as I want. Really appreciate if someone could help elucidate this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new variable to use a derivative value in the objective function:

```py
y = m.Var(0.5)
m.Equation(y==x.dt())
m.Minimize((y-0.5)**2)
```

Gekko includes every time point in the horizon to calculate the objective. Below is a simple script that demonstrates how to define the objective function that includes the derivative of `x`.

[image: Results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,11)
x = m.Var(0)
y = m.Var(0.5)
m.Equation(y==x.dt())
m.Minimize((y-0.5)**2)

m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot([0,10],[0.5,0.5],'r-',label='dx/dt=0.5')
plt.plot(m.time,y,'b:',label='y')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot([0,10],[0,5],'r-',label='dx/dt=0.5')
plt.plot(m.time,x,'b:',label='x')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You can also adjust the number of `NODES` in the derivative calculation for higher accuracy with [Orthogonal Collocation on Finite Elements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation). This is set with `m.options.NODES=3` between `2` and `6`. The default is `2`.

It is also possible to switch to `IMODE=3` and have more control over the discretization of the differential equation. Here is the equivalent problem with backwards difference Euler's method:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
n = 11
tm = np.linspace(0,n-1,n)
x = m.Array(m.Var,n)
y = m.Array(m.Var,n)
m.Equation(x[0]==0) # initial conditions
m.Equation(y[0]==0.5)
m.Equations([(tm[i]-tm[i-1])*y[i]==x[i]-x[i-1] 
             for i in range(1,n)])
for i in range(n):
    m.Minimize((y[i]-0.5)**2)

m.options.IMODE=3
m.solve(disp=False)

print(f'y: {y}')
print(f'x: {x}')
```

Some slight modification is needed for the forward difference formula for approximation of the derivative values:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
n = 11
tm = np.linspace(0,n-1,n)
x = m.Array(m.Var,n)
y = m.Array(m.Var,n)
m.Equation(x[0]==0) # initial condition
m.Equations([(tm[i+1]-tm[i])*y[i]==x[i+1]-x[i] 
             for i in range(0,n-1)])
m.Equation(y[-1]==y[-2]) # final condition
for i in range(n):
    m.Minimize((y[i]-0.5)**2)

m.options.IMODE=3
m.solve(disp=False)

print(f'y: {y}')
print(f'x: {x}')
```

They both produce the same answer as above:

```
y: [[0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5] [0.5]]
x: [[0.0] [0.5] [1.0] [1.5] [2.0] [2.5] [3.0] [3.5] [4.0] [4.5] [5.0]]
```

where the derivative of x is `y=0.5` and `x` is a line that starts at zero and has a slope of `0.5`.

Comment: Hi John, I really appreciate your response - it works perfectly. Anyway, I would like to benchmark the result from GEKKO against results from other software, where the objective function was computed using finite difference. So, it would be ideal if I can also do that in GEKKO so that benchmarking is done on the same basis. Do you have any suggestion in this case? If the above is the only option, it is completely fine anyway. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure, `NODES`=2 has only 2 collocation points per step, so it is equivalent to a finite difference. Otherwise, you'll need to switch to `IMODE=3` and not use the `.dt()` operator. I've included an example in the code of how to do that.

Comment: One other consideration is that `gekko` discretization with `IMODE=6` is more computationally efficient for compile time than `IMODE=3` because the core model is compiled once and propagated to the nodes of the horizon. They should both have the same efficiency beyond the compile time.

Comment: Dear John, Thank you very much for your detailed answers and solutions as always. I think I have enough material/knowledge to finish my current research now. Really appreciate your help. Prakitr